# JSON: How to parse the JSON string which contains "object":"page"

Tags: json, c#-4.0, json.net

We receive JSON data from Facebook Real Time subscription. The JSON itself contains property like "object":"page" and we need to access this property.

```
{
   "entry":[
  {
     "changes":[  ],
     "id":"1037501376337008",
     "time":1465883784
  }
   ],"object":"page"
}
```

We use dynamic object to parse the JSON but when we try to access the result.object, it is not allowed as object is the keyword in C#.

```
dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonRealTimeNotification);
string objectType = result.object.ToString(); // This line does not build
```

We can replace the "object" by some text in the original JSON string and then parse but we are looking if there is a standard way to handle this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@object`:

```
dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonRealTimeNotification);
string objectType = result.@object.ToString();
```

This is the same syntax as is used when specifying a regular *verbatim identifier*.  From the [C# Language Specification, § 2.4.2 Identifiers (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670.aspx):

> The prefix "@" enables the use of keywords as identifiers, which is useful when interfacing with other programming languages. The character @ is not actually part of the identifier, so the identifier might be seen in other languages as a normal identifier, without the prefix. An identifier with an @ prefix is called a verbatim identifier.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6or79e).